# Proguard returned error 1 - no proguard.txt file in project bin folder?

Tags: android, proguard

I just started using proguard, and used a file found on this site as my proguard.cfg file:

> -optimizationpasses 5
>   -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
>   -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
>   -dontpreverify
>   -verbose
>   -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
>
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
>   -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
>   -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
>   -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
>   -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
>
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>       native ; }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
>       public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
>       public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); }
>
> -keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {    public void *(android.view.View); }
>
> -keepclassmembers enum * {
>       public static **[] values();
>       public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String); }
>
> -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *; }

when I get to the final step of a signed apk export using eclipse, I get the error:

> Proguard returned with error code 1. See console

The console states this:

> Proguard returned with error code 1. See console [2012-12-27 14:23:16
>   - FlashActivity] java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Liam\workspace\FlashActivity\bin\proguard.txt (The system
>   cannot find the file specified) [2012-12-27 14:23:16 - FlashActivity]
>     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) [2012-12-27 14:23:16 -
>   FlashActivity]    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>   [2012-12-27 14:23:16 - FlashActivity]     at
>   java.io.FileReader.(Unknown Source) [2012-12-27 14:23:16 -
>   FlashActivity]    at
>   proguard.FileWordReader.(FileWordReader.java:39) [2012-12-27
>   14:23:16 - FlashActivity]     at
>   proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseIncludeArgument(ConfigurationParser.java:217)
>   [2012-12-27 14:23:16 - FlashActivity]     at
>   proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:124)
>   [2012-12-27 14:23:16 - FlashActivity]     at
>   proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)

Judging by the output, I would say that there is supposed to be a `proguard.txt` file in my apps `bin` folder, and there isn't one.

What should this file contain if I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your Android SDK with the interactive `android` tool and then also update your project with

```
android update project --path MyProjectDirectory
```

This should create `proguard-project.txt` and update `project.properties` to point to this file.

Answer (score 3):

since adt 17, proguard config file is not proguard.cfg but proguard-project.txt

see http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements

Comment: I changed my project.properties file, and I still get the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

This issue also comes when eclipse is not able to read the progaurd file from the sdk directory.

For me the error came for the dump.txt file, even when it was present in my project.

I fixed this by changing the sdk path in the project.properties file

from

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

to

```
progaurd.config=D:\Backup\Desktops\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

where my sdk was located.

Answer (score 0):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}
```

Make sure minifyEnabled is false